# Mixing two linear regression models

Tags: regression, time-series

In time series analysis, I have one predictor $X_1$ that has a higher $R^2$ when regressed against $Y$ sampled at **10 minutes** interval. Another predictor $X_2$ has a lower error when fitted against $Y$ at **20 minutes** intervals. The predictors are built from different data sets and unrelated to each other.

For example, assuming we run two different regression models for $X_1$ (10 minutes horizon) and $X_2$ (20 minutes): at time $t_0$ the $X_1$ model predicts 10 and $X_2$ 30. Ten minutes later at time $t_1$ model $X_1$ forecasts 100.
So now, at time $t_1$, we have $X_1$ predicting 100 and the **previous** $X_2$ forecast calculated at $t_0$ predicting 30 effectively for the same horizon target $t_2$ 10 minutes out.

How do I address the two models overlapping horizons? I don't necessarily need to build two models, I'm trying to understand how this kind of time series problems can be dealt with.

Comment: 1. Your model omits an error term. If there's no error (observed data exactly equals your no-error RHS), significance can't even come into it. 2. Do you account for the serial correlation in your model?

Comment: Fixed. Autocorrelation is not required, I'm really more interested on how to practically blend the two models/predictors in one model.

Comment: If there's no time-correlation issue, how does fitting at 20 minute intervals instead of 10 minute intervals improve things?

Comment: The two $X$ variables are completely different. $X_2$ works better when applied to a longer term forecast because it uses a different set of data points unrelated to $X_1$ or $Y$.

Comment: I don't see how that helps. If there's no time-correlation issue anywhere (everything is independent of everything at a different time to it), going to half the frequency simply halves the amount of data.

Comment: Why are you not concerned that **X2** is only significant at 20 minute intervals? Have you looked at other intervals and *not* found significance? NOTE: I'm not saying that you *should* be concerned--it's not a red flag... Pink? Maybe...

Comment: @Glen_b I rephrased my question, I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @SteveS I should have wrote $R^2$ rather than significant. Please check my question again, I edited and added an example.

Comment: First, I'm not quite clear with about this point: Is the data *given* in 10 & 20 minute intervals or are you choosing these two intervals? Also, why are you running two separate regressions instead of a single regression with your two independent variables?

Comment: Last, I recently read [this](http://www.aeaweb.org/articles.php?doi=10.1257/jep.28.2.3) article (and really liked it!) on **Big Data**--your question made me think of this line: `"An important insight from machine learning is that averaging over many small models tends to give better out-of-sample prediction than choosing a single model."` Granted, "many" could be *hundreds* (i.e. not 2). Still, I thought the line might be relevant...

Comment: @SteveS Yes, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. I read about averaging models too, was wondering if there are other techniques. (I am choosing the Y sampling interval to better fit the models).

Comment: Well, I was just sort of throwing that out there... However, my advice would be to keep it simple (i.e. a single model incorporating both **X**'s). Remember: That higher R^2 could be purely due to chance--a result more of *data dredging* then anything else. Plus, recall that it's the out-of-sample **RMSE** that you should care about, not the **R^2**.

Comment: @SteveS I'm interested in the claim made there that the insight about model averaging comes from machine learning. Recently here (I think in a comment thread) I pointed out to someone that in statistics the practice (model averaging over potentially less complex models instead of selecting a single model) goes back many decades.

Comment: Most of the time I really hate it when people go on and on about their datasets ("*Just get to the damn question already!*"). However, this may be one time where explaining a little bit about the type of data you're working with (e.g. financial? biological? *Tweets*??) could really help sort out the best approach to take as far as choosing the right model & timescale goes...

Comment: @Glen_b: Well, you'll have to take that up with the author (Hal Varian)... Actually, I think he's not trying to credit the *machine learning* crowd with *inventing* the technique, but rather to suggest that they're doing a great job of actually implementing this idea *in practice*. Also note: It's an Economics article; hence, I think he's saying that with economists in mind (and not trying to make a general statement)... In other words, you make a good point.

Comment: @Glen_b: My mistake for taking that quotation out of context... Anyway, unless you really can't stand Economics (you certainly would not be alone), you should definitely check it out--Varian is the chief economist over at Google (so the dude knows about Big Data). Plus, the particular journal is geared towards non-specialists so you won't find a more readable academic journal in Economics.